# JQuery See through dialog overlay

Tags: jquery, dom, plugins

There are several JQuery plugins to put a modal dialog and show a dom element in the dialog. But I'm looking for a dialog overlay which can show some portion of the screen and these region should be accessible, while other elements should be blocked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've put together a simple plugin to do this... Not sure the extent of your requirements, but it shouldn't be too hard to build on it.

Basic usage is as follows (note that if your selector matches multiple elements, it will just mask the first):

```
$("#yourDiv").mask();
```

Masking another element will unmask other masked elements or you can explicitly unmask things with:

```
$("#yourDiv").unmask();
```

Plugin code:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.mask = function() {
        this.unmask();

        var totalWidth = $(document).width();
        var totalHeight = $(document).height();

        var target = this.first();
        var maskWidth = target.outerWidth();
        var maskHeight = target.outerHeight();
        var maskOffset = target.offset();

        addMask(0, 0, maskOffset.left, totalHeight);                                                                    //left
        addMask(maskOffset.left + maskWidth, 0, totalWidth - (maskOffset.left + maskWidth), totalHeight);                 //right
        addMask(maskOffset.left, 0, maskWidth, maskOffset.top);                                                         //top
        addMask(maskOffset.left, maskOffset.top + maskHeight, maskWidth, totalHeight - (maskOffset.top + maskHeight));    //bottom

        var btn = $("<input type='button' value='Cancel' class='mask' />");
        $("body").append(btn);
        btn.css({ position: "absolute", zIndex: 9999, top: (maskOffset.top + maskHeight + 5), left: (maskOffset.left + maskWidth - btn.outerWidth(true)) });
        btn.click(function() { $(this).unmask(); });

        return this;
    };
    $.fn.unmask = function() {
        $(".mask").fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });
    };

    function addMask(x, y, w, h) {
        var mask = $("<div class='mask'></div>");
        mask.css({ position: "absolute", zIndex: 9999, width: w, height: h, top: y, left: x, display: "none" });
        //comment out this line & replace with css styles on 'div.mask' if you want to customise
        mask.css({ backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.3, filter: "alpha(opacity=30)" });
        $("body").append(mask);
        mask.fadeIn();
        // mask.click(function() { $(this).unmask(); });
    }
})( jQuery );
```

**Edit**: Bug fix with the panel dimensions, added a fade in/out & now <del>removes the mask if you click outside you're masked region</del> has a cancel button to remove the mask.

**Edit 2**: [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6kpp/3/)

Comment: Thanks Alconja. This is outstanding! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also wanted to ask if, we can make the overlay a modal overlay. And the overlay will go away only when clicking a button on the overlay?

Comment: @Manoj - Updated the code to have a cancel button (see updated fiddle for demo)... is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, That is perfect! Thanks Alconja

Answer (score 0):

Make z-index for items you want to show bigger than the one that overlay has
NOTE: Remember that z-index is relative, and be careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I hate to suggest the jQuery Tools library, what you're looking for is called an "expose" http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/toolbox/expose/index.html

Comment: Why is that out of curiosity?

Comment: the author appears to have lost interest and no longer supports the library

Answer (score 0):

I use [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plug in. Lets you block the whole page, or individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Alconja's answer is more elegant than this, and this is really meant more as a demonstration, but you can see here what's going on. The overlay is a grid with eight blocks, with the middle block being the form area that is exposed.

Make sure and inspect the elements with Firebug or Chrome console to see how the elements are displayed and the css styles are applied.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="test">
        <div>
            Text: <input type="text"/> <input type="button" value="Undo"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            Text: <input type="text"/> <input type="button"value="Undo"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            Text: <input type="text"/> <input type="button"value="Undo"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#test {
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 330px;
}
#test div {
  background: #ffa;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.overlay {
  background: #dda;
  opacity: .6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

function setOverlay(top, left, width, height) {
    var screenwidth = parseInt($('body').width());
    var screenheight = parseInt($('body').height());
    var topleft = [0, 0, left, top];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+topleft[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+topleft[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+topleft[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+topleft[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var topmiddle = [0, left, width, top];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+topmiddle[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+topmiddle[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+topmiddle[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+topmiddle[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var topright = [0, left+width, screenwidth-left-width, top];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+topright[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+topright[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+topright[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+topright[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var centerleft = [top, 0, left, height];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+centerleft[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+centerleft[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+centerleft[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+centerleft[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var centerright = [top, left+width, screenwidth-left-width, height];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+centerright[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+centerright[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+centerright[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+centerright[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var bottomleft = [top+height, 0, left, screenheight-top-height];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+bottomleft[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+bottomleft[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+bottomleft[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+bottomleft[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var bottommiddle = [top+height, left, width, screenheight-top-height];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+bottommiddle[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+bottommiddle[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+bottommiddle[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+bottommiddle[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var bottomright = [top+height, left+width, screenwidth-left-width, screenheight-top-height];
    $('<div class="overlay" style="top: '+bottomright[0]+'px; '+
                  'left: '+bottomright[1]+'px; '+
                  'width: '+bottomright[2]+'px; '+
                  'height: '+bottomright[3]+'px;"></div>').appendTo('body');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function(){
        $this = $(this).parent();
        $('input[value="Undo"]').click();
        setOverlay(
            parseInt($this.offset().top),
            parseInt($this.offset().left),
            parseInt($this.outerWidth()),
            parseInt($this.outerHeight())
        );
    });
    $('input[value="Undo"]').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').remove();        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3nRLJ/