# create an overlay, but allow a certain area to show through?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to overlay the content on my page with a black opaque overlay, either with an opaque image or background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6).

but, I want to be able to define an area of the page where the overlay doesn't cover, so that part of the page shows through clearly.like the example below:

[image]

Can use css/ jquery whatever is needed

Comment: Related (dup?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251670/jquery-see-through-dialog-overlay

Comment: There is no straight forward way. You can perhaps consider having a large PNG image (dimension wise) which is pre-filled with `rgba(0,0,0,0.6)` except for one block. You can move around the element containing this image to cover/uncover areas you need in the grid.

Comment: Not with `CSS` alone, it's almost like an inverse `clip:` property you need - which currently doesn't exist http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery overlay. Something like

```
$("#box").overlay({
    effect: "default",
    mask: {
      color: "#999",
      loadSpeed: 200,
      opacity: 0.8
    },
    oneInstance: true,
    closeOnClick: false,
    closeOnEsc: false
  });
```